# How does RunKeeper's Breeze app stay running in the background?

Tags: ios

I'm working on figuring out how RunKeeper's Breeze iOS app stays running in the background all the time. We're building something vaguely similar (uses step data, but does other things with it) and I need to do short processing on the incoming data every few minutes.

I've noticed a few things.

Breeze registers for the following background modes:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>location</string>
    <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

At first I thought maybe they were using silent notifications to bring the app back to life on regular intervals, but it seems the system holds silent notifications unless the device is plugged in, so that limits its use for this application.

In the battery usage area it says Background Location under the Breeze app. We've set up background location updates which work fantastic for a while, but the system eventually suspends the app. We've also set up significant location updates, but that brings us back at most every 20 minutes or so, if at all. Then we're suspended again after a few moments. Which makes sense for that API.

Another interesting thing I've noticed is if you manually kill the Breeze app from the task list, you immediately get a local notification telling you to relaunch the app. Perhaps this is from applicationWillTerminate, but will this get called if the system suspends the app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cory,

I'm an engineer on Breeze, and I can give you some insight into how it works. Breeze does not run continuously in the background, but it does wake up frequently via all the methods you listed above (location, background fetch, and silent push).

Background location (with autopause turned off) will give you near continuous execution in the background, but it has a severe battery cost as the CPU can never sleep. I wouldn't recommend it!

Breeze allows both autopause and when it is actively using "best" accuracy location data, it also employs deferred updates. We use significant location updates only due to a bug/shortcoming that requires significant location change to start/stop standard location services in the background. When we are using significant location services (usually after you've been still for awhile), we use region monitoring (geofences) to trigger higher accuracy location data again. As the app is woken by location services, it checks motion data from the M7 to determine how location services (and other high battery drain activities) should be adjusted.

Secondly, we use background fetch to wake the app, perform the same motion data checks. Background fetch occurs throughout the day, and you can specify an interval between fetches, but that is not guaranteed. Breeze primarily uses the minimum interval, but does its own rate limiting, so is not executing significant work every time it wakes up. Background fetch occurs more frequently when the phone is awake (and often when the user has the phone open and is doing other things).

The final app wakeup is silent push, as you noticed. This is essentially a fallback, if our servers have not heard from a client app in awhile, a silent push will be used to wake the app up. It has not been our experience that silent pushes are only delivered to an app that is plugged in, but they are certainly not guaranteed reliable.

The applicationWillTerminate local notification is a failsafe primarily for iOS7, where killing an app via the task list will prevent it from receiving silent push notifications. I believe this is no longer the case in iOS8.

Thanks for your interest in Breeze, it's a very fun product to work on!

Comment: Thanks for the great insight! Did you notice if changing the location accuracy changes how often and how long the app is allowed to run in the background? Also when significant location services wakes you up, are you allowed to run for very long? It seems like when this happens we only get a couple minutes no matter what, then suspended again.

Comment: Changing the location accuracy will change how frequently your app is woken up, but if points stop being delivered (loss of gps or accuracy is low), the app will be suspended again. Usually at kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters or higher you're receiving points at 1hz.  
  
Using beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler can give you extra time to finish execution (I believe it caps at 2 minutes in iOS 7/8, used to be 10 minutes). However, if you always hit the 2 minute expiration or don't close the background tasks yourself when finished, iOS will be more aggressive in suspending your app.

Comment: Hi @gossnj , I have a question regarding another Runkeeper functionality namely playing audio while in background. If by any chance you see this can you please check my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49665277/how-to-initiate-audio-while-app-is-in-background ?